# AKS pod creation failure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

AKS pod creation is failing with below error

```
Warning  FailedMount  10m (x428 over 3d23h)  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[dsc-nfs], unattached volumes=[linkerd-identity-end-entity linkerd-identity-token linkerd-proxy-init-xtables-lock kube-api-access-74dnj dsc-nfs]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount  2m4s (x2844 over 4d)   kubelet  MountVolume.MountDevice failed for volume "dsc-pv-stg7222p010-fs01" : rpc error: code = Internal desc = volume(dsc-nfs-vol-001) mount //stg7222p010.file.core.windows.net/stg7222p010-fs01 on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/file.csi.azure.com/6a0bdfa66164184e7a8d79a1f2ce303dfca172956d2405021d1a6278b29f9a85/globalmount failed with mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=0,gid=0,mfsymlinks,cache=strict,nosharesock,nobrl,actimeo=30,<masked> //stg7222p010.file.core.windows.net/stg7222p010-fs01 /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/file.csi.azure.com/6a0bdfa66164184e7a8d79a1f2ce303dfca172956d2405021d1a6278b29f9a85/globalmount
Output: mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Help in resolving the error

Comment: Would it be possible to share the pod manifest file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.